# Why does my Mac have Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD1?

Tags: mac

I have a VMWare virtual machine of 256GB. The HD capacity on the Mac is 750GB. In terminal under the Volumes folder, I see Macintosh HD and Macintosh HD1. About 300 gigs seem to be wasted.

How do I cleanup the hard drive and why do I have 2 HDs?

Answer (score 1):

When you installed your vmware, you must have partitioned your HD and allocated some storage to the virtual OS. Macintosh HD 1 is the result of a partitioned drive. If you go to disk utility you will be able to see this. I am not sure if you can undo the partition without formatting the entire drive.

Comment: It is possible to just format the VMWare drive and leave Macintosh HD untouched. Just delete Macintosh HD1 on disk utility.

Comment: HD 1 - looks like a mirror of HD

@kevin9794 I deleted the HD1 via DaisyDisky utility and everything seems to be ok. Mac boots up fine, VM works fine and I got back about 250 gigs.

Comment: Awesome! Interesting that it looks like a mirror and good to know you solved your problem (: I suggest you select a correct answer to officially "close" the question, btw.